# Gridview - Loop through multiple header rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In a console app, a gridview is created dynamically.

```
        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            BoundField boundfield = new BoundField();
            boundfield.DataField = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
            boundfield.HeaderText = arr[i].ToString();// dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
            gv.Columns.Add(boundfield);
        }
```

Then, two more header rows are added. Here is a partial of one row:

```
        GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
        TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();

        HeaderCell.Text = "";
        HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 4;
        HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

        //more header cells added then another row here

        gv.DataSource = dt;
        gv.DataBind();

        gv.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow);
```

Using a `foreach` loop, adjusting separate cell borders not in the header is done:

```
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
        {               
            TableCell tCell = row.Cells[0];
            tCell.Attributes["style"] = "border-right:0";               
        }
```

I have been trying to find a way to loop through the header rows and adjust some borders on the cells.

Tried using `foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.HeaderRow)` but `gv.HeaderRow` does not have a public definition for `GetEnumerator`.

Tried `for(int i = 0; i < gv.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried a for loop?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
GridViewRow headerRow = gv.HeaderRow;            
TableCell hCell = headerRow.Cells[0];
hCell.Attributes["style"] = "border-right:0";
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That helps somewhat. HeaderCell.Attributes["style"] = "border-top:0"; worked but HeaderCell.Attributes["style"] = "border-bottom:0"; for some reason did not. It did not even show in the html. Also, I need to adjust the original header that the gridview creates.