# Accessing the second row in Header in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have multiple headers in my gridview. I add them in row created event. They all work fine. Now i want to access the textboxes (P, P1, C, C1) in second and third row in the header and get/set its value. How do i do this?

gridView.HeaderRow.FindControl is not getting me the text box. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4 Header5
            P   P1
            C   C1
Data1   Data2   Data3   Data4   Data5
Data1   Data2   Data3   Data4   Data5
Data1   Data2   Data3   Data4   Data5
Data1   Data2   Data3   Data4   Data5
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattdotson/archive/2006/03/01/real-world-gridview-two-headed-grouping-gridviews.aspx it should explain how to create and access the elements. From what I understand you would need to access headerRow and iterate over it like here [Gridview - Loop through multiple header rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559072/gridview-loop-through-multiple-header-rows)

Comment: Hi John, thanks. I tried looping the header rows but gridview.HeaderRow does not return a collection. It is just a single row and only the headers (header 1...5) in this case.

Comment: Are you sure that you actually added multiple headers and not just two rows with the elements (P, P1) and (C, C1)? If not then take your DataTable object which you assigned to gridView and try "nameofdatatable".Rows[0][1] and if this content is "P" you have added them as row elements not as second header.